# WSO2IS resident IdP configuration

Tags: configuration, wso2-identity-server

there are multiple posts / blogs how to configure a WSO2 IS resident IdP. Great. Is there a way how to configure the resident SAML IdP (EntityId) ?

g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way to configure.

Log in to IS management console and In "Home" under "Identity" section click on "List" in "Identity Providers" subsection. Once you get to "Identity Providers" page, You'll see a "Resident Identity Provider" Link with a red icon. Click that link and you will go to Resident Identity Provider configuration page. In that page click on the "Inbound Authentication Configuration" (It will expand) then click "SAML2 Web SSO Configuration", it will also expand and there you will see a text box to edit the idpEntityId, with the label "Identity Provider Entity Id"

Comment: Thank you, that definitely answers the question.. I was incomplete in my question - indeed I could use a management console, but is it possible to use a configuration file to support automated deployment? I thought that the SSO/EntityID element in the identity.xml transforms into the resident IdP metadata (Entity ID), but apparently I still missing something. We don't want admins to configure environment manually for each deployment (or the database reg config is the only way?) Thank you in advance for any tip.

Comment: For the completeness - I've checked the source codes and in future versions it suppose to be fixed - the Entity ID of the Resident IdP will be read from the identity.xml config file correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. yes it's fixed https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/commit/104c4e33fa407c66b58dfbf05660a213965e7eb7